# How to create a workflow template

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-addin, template

The official Microsoft documentation includes the [following sentence](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/develop-sharepoint-workflows-using-visual-studio):

> A workflow can be written as a template so that after it is deployed,
>   it can be reused and associated with any list or library.

How can I create a workflow template? I only know the list workflow (bound to a defined list) and the page workflow, both deployed as a SharePoint add-in.

Neither of them can be reused.

I would like to develop a workflow that I can add to any list in SharePoint. Similar to the reusable workflow in SharePoint Designer.

Answer (score 1):

After some more attempts I found a solution.

If you create a list workflow and do not bind it to a list, it is available as a template in SharePoint.